# How to read a file from blob using pandas if it has a list like directory structure inside it?

Tags: python, pandas, azure, blob, azure-data-lake-gen2

Tried accesing a file stored in a Azure Data Lake Storage using pandas read_csv method. But facing issue as the folder path is interpreted as a list. Is there any way to explicity specify pandas that its a  path and not list?
The issue is with the  "Type - ['D']" mentioned in the path

```
import pandas as pd

datalake_connection_string = "<connection_string_for_the_container>"

data=pd.read_csv(f"abfs://container_name@storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net/OutputFiles/CodeOutputs/Type - ['D']/SOLUTIONS/summary.csv",storage_options={"connection_string": datalake_connection_string})
```

The Error I'm facing is as below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data=pd.read_csv(f"abfs://container_name@storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net/OutputFiles/CodeOutputs/Type - ['D']/SOLUTIONS/summary.csv",storage_options={"connection_string": ADLSConnectionString})

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg.<locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    209     else:
    210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:331, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    326     warnings.warn(
    327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
    328         FutureWarning,
    329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
    330     )
--> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:950, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    935 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    936     dialect,
    937     delimiter,
   (...)
    946     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
    947 )
    948 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 950 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:605, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    602 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    604 # Create the parser.
--> 605 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    607 if chunksize or iterator:
    608     return parser

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1442, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
   1439     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
   1441 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
-> 1442 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py:1735, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1733     if "b" not in mode:
   1734         mode += "b"
-> 1735 self.handles = get_handle(
   1736     f,
   1737     mode,
   1738     encoding=self.options.get("encoding", None),
   1739     compression=self.options.get("compression", None),
   1740     memory_map=self.options.get("memory_map", False),
   1741     is_text=is_text,
   1742     errors=self.options.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
   1743     storage_options=self.options.get("storage_options", None),
   1744 )
   1745 assert self.handles is not None
   1746 f = self.handles.handle

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:713, in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    710     codecs.lookup_error(errors)
    712 # open URLs
--> 713 ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
    714     path_or_buf,
    715     encoding=encoding,
    716     compression=compression,
    717     mode=mode,
    718     storage_options=storage_options,
    719 )
    721 handle = ioargs.filepath_or_buffer
    722 handles: list[BaseBuffer]

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py:409, in _get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    406     pass
    408 try:
--> 409     file_obj = fsspec.open(
    410         filepath_or_buffer, mode=fsspec_mode, **(storage_options or {})
    411     ).open()
    412 # GH 34626 Reads from Public Buckets without Credentials needs anon=True
    413 except tuple(err_types_to_retry_with_anon):

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:441, in open(urlpath, mode, compression, encoding, errors, protocol, newline, **kwargs)
    391 def open(
    392     urlpath,
    393     mode="rb",
   (...)
    399     **kwargs,
    400 ):
    401     """Given a path or paths, return one ``OpenFile`` object.
    402 
    403     Parameters
   (...)
    439     ``OpenFile`` object.
    440     """
--> 441     return open_files(
    442         urlpath=[urlpath],
    443         mode=mode,
    444         compression=compression,
    445         encoding=encoding,
    446         errors=errors,
    447         protocol=protocol,
    448         newline=newline,
    449         expand=False,
    450         **kwargs,
    451     )[0]

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:195, in OpenFiles.__getitem__(self, item)
    194 def __getitem__(self, item):
--> 195     out = super().__getitem__(item)
    196     if isinstance(item, slice):
    197         return OpenFiles(out, mode=self.mode, fs=self.fs)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can any one please suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to break it down using something like os.path.join.  This worked for me (on linux):

```
import pandas as pd
import os
srcFile = r"file.csv"
srcFolder = r"/projects/proj_42_python/Type - ['D']/"
srcPath = os.path.join(srcFolder,srcFile)
pd.read_csv(srcPath)
```

Comment: The problem here is that the file is sitting inside Azure Data Lake, so we can't really use the os.path.join as its not in an operating system

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

You can use the below code to read a file from a blob using pandas if it has a list-like directory structure inside it.

In that structure the **`Type - ['D']`**  for each quotation mark there should be a backward slash to make it redirect to the right path.
You can get the Blob SAS Url from the portal:

[image]

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd 
source ='https://storage6780.blob.core.windows.net/test/OutputFiles/CodeOutputs/Type%20-%20%5B\'D\'%5D/SOLUTIONS/sample.csva?<Your SAS Token>'
df = pd.read_csv(source,encoding="ISO-8859-1")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#directory-names)

Comment: Tried this approach and it worked but there are so many files in this folder that, even writing a function to generate the SAS URL is not advisable. That is the reason I'm using the abfs or abfss protocol to read from this folder.

The below code snipper worked for me but, looking for a more generic way which can also work for other braces like '()' or '{}' 
`data=pd.read_csv(f"abfs://container_name@storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net/OutputFiles/CodeOutputs/Type - [[]'D'[]]/SOLUTIONS/summary.csv",storage_options={"connection_string": datalake_connection_string})`